# XCTest Xcode 7 beta 3 swift 2 initiate View Controller from storyboard issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uistoryboard, xctest

I have this code in XCTest setup

```
var passcodeVC:HNPasscodeViewController!
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))
    self.passcodeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HNPasscodeViewController") as! HNPasscodeViewController
    self.passcodeVC.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Xcode gives me error "Could not cast value of type" on this line

```
self.passcodeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HNPasscodeViewController") as! HNPasscodeViewController
```

I'm using Swift 2.0 with Xcode 7 beta 3. I tried bundle:

```
nil
NSBundle.mainBundle()
NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder) 
NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType) (Xcode doesn't autocomplete this but gives me no error)
```

I also added the custom view controller class to compile list and Main storyboard to resource of the test target.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making all my custom classes public to the test target. I use this new test declaration in swift 2

```
@testable import <my module name>
```

It works well now.